# Android GraphView plot only points on graph and change X axis position

Tags: android, plot, android-graphview

I'm trying to create a graph on android using the android graphview library.

1)I need to plot points on the graph (Currently, the options are LineGraph and BarGraph) however i wish to only plot the points without drawing a line.

2) Change the positioning of the X axis and it's labels(such that it shows on the top and not the bottom).

I'm looking through the API but cannot find a way to do these things. Would really appreciate if anyone could help out!

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible do to exactly that what you want with android GraphView but should not be hard to modify the library to do so, because the features already exists.

1. LineGraphView can draw data points.
   take a look at the methods

   - setDrawDataPoints
   - setDataPointsRadius
2. BarGraphView can draw the labels on top of the bar
   take a look at the method

   - setDrawValuesOnTop